# can i do multiple things in one command on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm testing something where I'm compiling some code and analysing output with a Perl script.

So first I run make, manually copy & paste the output to *errors.txt* and then running my Perl script (running: perl analysis.pl) in terminal.

Is there away I can do this just with one line in bash?

Comment: how you are reading errors.txt in your perl script?

Comment: i just open it and open another file (.html) analyse the text from the error.txt and prints to the .html. So all i have to do is build then refresh the page to get formatted error text(the terminal output from make is silly :P).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
make > error.txt 2>&1 ; perl analysis.pl
```

We are redirecting the `stdout` and `stderr` of `make` to a file called error.txt and then irrespective of the make success or failure we are running the `Perl` script( which knows to read from `error.txt`)

If you want the Perl script to be run only when `make` succeeds you can use `&&` in place of `;`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo yes && echo youcan
```

`Yes` will be echoed first, if it executes fine, then only `youcan` is echoed, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the exact command

```
make > errors.txt && ./my_perl_script
```